# A Sobolev function

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to prove that the function $$u(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}|x-r_k|^{-\alpha}$$ is in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(B_1(0))$ if $0<\alpha<\frac{n-p}{p}$ where the sequence $ (r_k)$ is dense in the unit ball. I managed to prove this for every single summand of this series but I do not see why is series is even well-defined. Does someone have a hint for me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Were you able to estimate the $W^{1,p}$ norm of an individual summand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $W^{1,p}$ norm of $|r-r_k|^\alpha$ is bounded:
$$
\int_{|x|\le1}|x-r_k|^{-\alpha p}\,dx=\int_{|x-r_k|\le1}|x|^{-\alpha p}\,dx\le\int_{|x|\le2}|x|^{-\alpha p}\,dx.
$$
Similarly for the gradient. Let $C$ be a bound. Then
$$
\bigl\|2^{-k}\,|x-r_k|^{-\alpha}\bigr\|_{1,p}=2^{-k}\,\bigl\||x-r_k|^{-\alpha}\bigr\|_{1,p}\le C\,2^{-k}.
$$
Since $\sum 2^{-k}<\infty$ and $W^{1,p}$ is a Banach space, the series converges in $W^{1,p}$ (it also converges pointwise on $B_1(0)\setminus\{r_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$.)

Comment: The $W^{1,p}$ norm  depends on the position of $r_k$ in the unit ball and thus isn't independent of $k$, but it can be estimated independently of $k$. So a small additional arguemnt is needed here.

Comment: Right. I was thinking of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I delete the answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer and undeleted it.

Comment: Shouldn't the integration domain become$ |x+r_k|\le1$ in the first equality?. asume you are making a change of variable $y=x-r_k$so I get$ |y+r_k|$ and then rename $y$ as $x$